# C# Most performant way of counting sections in a string, by delimiter

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need to process a lot of strings that represent file paths, and I want to get the number of "segments" in the full path (e.g. the drive, 2 folders and the file) as separated by the .  E.g.:

```
"C:\Some Folder\Some Folder\somefile.txt"
```

What's the fastest way (in terms of computational performance) to work that out?

Would it simply be:

```
int pathCount = myPath.Split(new string[1] { @"\" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Count();
```

Note, I'd declare the string[] as a variable that can be reused.

**Update** - I'm not fussy on how the count is arrived at: counting the instances of the delimiter or the segments in between.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to count the delimiters in the path?

Comment: @JeffMercado - yes; feel free to post an answer.

Comment: This seems like it would be very easy to benchmark with different solutions to find out the "most performant" method inf your particular environment.

Comment: @itsme86 - true, but I was interested in any guidance or ideas other had; such as Martins idea - which never would have occurred to me.  And I'm not exactly sure why this is attracting so many down votes - if it's that bad it might help me if people said why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way would definitely be to go through the string character by character and count the number of delimiters.

```
int sectionCount = 1;
foreach ( var character in inputString )
{
   if ( character == '\\' )
   {
      sectionCount++;
   }
}
```

Note that we start the counter with 1 to account for the first section before we find a first delimiter. In case the input has no delimiters, it has basically one section, hence the invariant holds.

Comment: You're suggesting that counting every character is 'definitely' faster than using an expression or string method?  Is there any basis to that assertion?  I would have thought that would have been the slowest.

Comment: I would suggest trying this over several thousand iterations to see the performance results, but it should definitely be much faster. If you check the source of .NET, you can see that the code for `Split` is fairly complex and will have a big performance overhead over simple char iteration. Also, it requires creating several new instances of strings for each of the sections, again adding memory overhead. Here is the link to the source - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,baabf9ec3768812a

Comment: Thanks - yes I was thinking split would be an expensive operation.  As you say, I'll need to do some testing.

Comment: In the most abstract view, string is just an array of chars, so iterating over it is a pretty fast operation and has the lowest possible complexity if you want to find all sections - `O(N)`. You might be able to make the code a little faster using `unsafe` and pointers, but the difference would be absolutely negligible.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I compared some different approaches and this was the fastest - it would never have occurred to me to take that approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about the number and don't actually care about extracting the split tokens, it's simpler (and faster) to do:

```
int pathCount = myPath.Count(c => c == '\\') + 1;
```

On a side note, you might also want to consider the '/' case, as the forward slash is also legal for Windows path delimiting.

Comment: dont forget about ```Path.DirectorySeparatorChar```